# How to use product excerpt to look for a db row, find a field value and use it to assign post type pr. category

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, logic

We are working on a little project, and cannot get it to work properly. Quick info: someone fills out a form, info sends to sql database and creates a wordpress post type product (using zapier)

We are trying to make wordpress get the new post's excerpt, find the row, where the first column would have same value as the excerpt and then in that row look for a column with certain name to  see whether it is null or not. If not null, we want get that value of field  and assign this value as post type product's category.

Ex: If value is glasses, products category  would also  be glasses. We tried this code (using $wpdb ) , however it did not work properly, and as  we are relatively new to php and  would really appreciate your insight...

```
 add_action( 'xmlrpc_call', 'prepare_woocommerce_check' );


function prepare_woocommerce_check( $action ) {``if ( 'wp.newPost' === $action ) {
    add_action( 'save_post', 'validate_woocommerce_product' );}}

function validate_woocommerce_product( $product_id ) {

remove_action( 'save_post', 'validate_woocommerce_product' );

$product = wc_get_product( $product_id )


$product->set_regular_price(22);


    $myexcerpt = apply_filters('the_excerpt', get_the_excerpt($product_id));

    global $wpdb;

    $result =$wpdb-> get_results("SELECT select FROM info WHERE  clienid == $myexcerpt");
    if ($result) {

    function wp_insert_term() {

    wp_insert_term($result, "product_cat");

    }

    add_action('init','wp_insert_term');






$product->save();
```

}

Comment: SELECT select FROM info WHERE  clienid == $myexcerpt is not correct, sql uses = and not ==

Comment: Thanks, fixed it. Though still does not work. Is there a problem with the structure of code?